# Most common resolution used in Android phones as of 2013

Tags: android, resolution, statistics

Before making an Android app, I want to know what screen resolutions I should target. I know there are resolutions of 1280x800, 1280x720 and 800x480, but I would like to know which are most common.

Are there any recent stats on the distribution of Android devices' screen resolutions?

Comment: Choose a resolution-independent UI library (like the built in one) and forget about screen resolutions.

Comment: Can I help? Curiosly, my post is on "On Hold" state. What can I do or what should you suggest me something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick snapshot of the information on current android devices can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

The site is kept up to date every 14-days based on devices which access the Google Play Store so its a pretty decent source for information.

Comment: Pretty useful. I'll keep on noted. :-)